# Overriding, Overridden Function

Tags: c#

here's what I am trying to do

```
class A
{
    virtual void foo();
}

class B : A
{
    virtual override void foo();
}

class C : B
{
    override void foo();
}
```

so what I want to see when calling C.foo() is
A.foo(), B.foo(), C.foo()

but I dont think virtual override can be used in the same function definition. How would I go around this?

Thanks
-Mike

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding `virtual`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overridden functions are automatically `virtual`, unless explicitly declared `sealed`.

Note that calling `C.Foo()` will not call `B.Foo()` or `A.Foo()` unless `C.Foo` manually calls `base.Foo()`.

Comment: yea I understand I am sorry I was alittle lazy to write everything out. There is a base.foo in both B and C foo functions. but so if I call override void foo() { base.foo(); } in C would that call B.foo() or A.foo()?

Comment: `C`'s base class is `B`.  Therefore, it will call `B.Foo`.  If `B` calls `base.Foo()`, that will in turn call `A.Foo`

Answer (score 2):

code should work like this:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void foo() {}
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void foo() {}
}

class C : B
{
    public override void foo() {}
}
```

so long as foo is accessible. no need for 'virtual' in `B`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
class A
    {
        public virtual void foo()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A");
        }
    }

    class B : A
    {
        public override void foo()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("B");
            base.foo();
        }
    }

    class C : B
    {
        public override void foo()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("C");
            base.foo();
        }
    }


C c = new C();
c.foo();
```